# What role (if any) does verbal intelligence play in one's aptitude for science or mathematics?

Tags: cognitive-psychology, intelligence

I am looking for scientific literature that suggests a link between verbal intelligence (i.e. one's capacity for reading comprehension and use of language) and one's aptitude for working with or producing novel thought in STEM fields such as the hard sciences (chemistry, physics), mathematics, and/or computer science. If there does not appear to be a link, I'd like scientific literature that expresses why this would be the case.

Comment: How do you define "successes"? If you are thinking on getting grant money in, than I bet excellent verbalization/writing skills are a plus.

Comment: I meant more along the lines of understanding and working with the subject(s). For instance, it is clear that quantitative intelligence plays a role in science, engineering, and mathematics. I am wondering to what extent (if any) verbal intelligence could play a role.

Comment: So in that case, would the metric be impact factor?

Comment: It would be great if you could define success - academic success can be meaured in a great many ways as @Seanny123 indicates - grant money, #articles, doing awesome research, Nature articles, owning ones own lab, ....

Comment: Agreed, too broad without defining "success."

Comment: Ah, OK, I see why the question was confusing. I've edited the question -- does my rewording make more sense?

Comment: It's still pretty vague--how does one define novel thought in a consistently measurable way?